# Create meetings in room calendar

Tags: powershell, calendar, exchange-server

I received a request to create a shared calendar in Exchange Online that includes team members planned vacations. I get data about vacations from another source with Powershell but now I need to somehow import it to that calendar.

Can anybody point me to right direction?

Comment: You can't do it in PowerShell but Microsoft Graph might work. I don't use Graph so I can only point you in that direction. :-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http